# Google charts JSON format for stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, php, json, charts

EDIT: I am looking for an example in the layout below. I may be missing something as this is my first time with Google Charts... Thanks for the help!

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Store 1","pattern":"","type":"number"},
        {"id":"","label":"Store 2","pattern":"","type":"number"},
        {"id":"","label":"Store 3","pattern":"","type":"number"},...
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"morning","f":'15'},{"v":"noon","f":'20'},{"v":"night","f":'25'}]},...
      ]
}
```

I cannot find anywhere an example of how the JSON record needs to be formatted for a stacked bar chart for Google Charts. I have tried a few combinations but I am struggling visualising it.

My data contains:

```
           Store 1   Store 2
store_id   walk-ins  walk-ins
morning      20        25
noon         35        40
night        50        55
```

There are 20 stores to chart stacking the values of each row.

My JSON right now looks like:

```
[{"store_id":"Store 1","time":"morning","walk-ins":"20"}, and so on...]
```

I am happy to share the PHP once I work out what it needs to format the record like! Can someone point me to an example that may exist that I have missed please. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [**Documentation**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart)?

The JSON format seems to be an array of arrays :

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);
```

that means your data would look like this:

```
[
    ["store_id", "time","walk-ins"],
    ["Store 1","morning","30"],
    ["Store 2","afternoon","40"],
    ["Store 3","night","50"]
]
```

Comment: I need to convert to JSON format as it is coming from a server script. I cannot seem to figure out which are cols and how to lay out rows in that format.

Comment: you would use json_decode for that, you need help with that?

Comment: You are missing my point (or more likely I am missing yours!). See my edit. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Hi meda, thanks for the help! I just tried to chat but got an "we are working on it". Are you on SKYPE?

Comment: hi meda, thanks for all the help but your suggestion did not work. Formatting the output record in the same format as the array data table examples does not work for JSON API.